# Tensorflow: how to restore only specific hidden layers from checkpoint and use them to build a different computational graph for inference?

Tags: tensorflow, restore, production

Let's say I trained a model with a very complex computational graph tailored for training. After a lot of training, the best model was saved to a checkpoint file. Now, I want to use the learned parameters of this best model for inference. However, the computational graph used for training is not exactly the same as the one I intend to use for inference. Concretely, there is a module in the graph with several layers in charge of outputting embedding vectors for items (recommender system context). However, for the sake of computational performance, during inference time I would like to have all the item embedding vectors precomputed in advance, so that the only computation required per request would just involve a couple of hidden layers.

Therefore, what I would like to know how to do is:

1. How to just restore the part of the network that outputs item embedding vectors, in order to precompute these vectors for all items (this would happen in some pre-processing script off-line)
2. Once all item embedding vectors are precomputed, during on-line inference time how to just restore the hidden layers in the later parts of the network and make them receive the precomputed item embedding vectors instead.

How can the points above be accomplished? I think point 1. is easier to get done. But my biggest concern is with point 2. In the computational graph used for training, in order to evaluate any layer I would have to provide values for the input placeholders. However, during on-line inference these placeholders would be obsolete because a lot of stuff would be precomputed and I don't know how to tell hidden layers in the later parts of the network that they should no longer depend on these obsolete placeholders but depend on the precomputed stuff instead.